# Disabling specific autocomplete in visual studio

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio, intellicode

Is there any way to control the below behaviour?

[image: Gif1]

When I type the letter x and press spacebar, visual studio autocompletes to using XmlReadMode, when i simply want to use x. Is there a way to control what vs autocompletes and what it doesn't? I don't want to turn the feature completely off.

I have looked into the settings for intellicode, however i can't see any settings for configuring it, only disabling it.

Comment: Well you have to start with a Type so you need to put that first.

Comment: i know what i'm doing there is invalid syntax, but i simply want to type the letter x and press the spacebar without it autocompleting, wherever i like. i know that "let" is also not valid in c# but there is similar behaviour with that too. if i type let and press the spacebar, it again autocompletes to the most similar word. regardless of whether it's valid syntax or not you should be able to type anything you like and then an error pop up afterwards :/ if not, it would be useful to be able to prioritise what to autocomplete TO?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Only solution is: Turn off intellisense autocompletion with spacebar and use only tab.

1. Tools > Options > Text Editor > Advanced > Default IntelliSense completion mode: > select Tab-only in the dropdown.
2. Restart Visual Studio.

See: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/answers/questions/760368/disabling-autocompletion-from-spacebar-in-vs-2022.html